# Handling non JSON response with a Body.json() promise

Tags: javascript, json, redux, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a scheme to intercept and handle requests from an API middleware, however, for whatever reason I'm unable to properly handle non JSON responses from my API endpoint. The following snippet works just fine for server responses formatted in JSON however say an user has an invalid token, the server returns a simple Unauthorized Access response that I'm unable to handle even though I am supplying an error callback to the json() promise. The Unauthorized Access response message is lost in the following scheme.

```
    const callAPI = () => { fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'credentials': 'include',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic bXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJbVY0Y0NJNk1UUTVPRE15TVRNeU5pd2lhV0YwSWpveE5EazRNak0wT1RJMmZRLmV5SnBaQ0k2TVgwLllFdWdKNF9YM0NlWlcyR2l0SGtOZGdTNkpsRDhyRE9vZ2lkNGVvaVhiMEU6'
        }
    });
    };

    return callAPI().then(res => {
        return res.json().then(responseJSON => {
            if(responseJSON.status === 200){
                return dispatch({
                    type: type[1],
                    data: responseJSON,
                    message: success
                });
            } else if(responseJSON.status === 401) {
                return dispatch({
                    type: type[2],
                    message: responseJSON.message
                });
            }
            return Promise.resolve(json);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err.toString(), ' an error occured');
        });
    }, err => {
        console.log('An error occured. Please try again.');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your response handling code in a `try...catch` block like this:

```
return callAPI().then(res => {
    try {
        return res.json().then(responseJSON => {
            [...]
    catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});
```

`Body.json()` throws when the body is actually not JSON. Therefore, you should check if the body contains JSON **before** you call `json()` on it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response.

Comment: How do you check to see if it contains JSON before calling json()? I don't see that in the doc you linked.

Comment: @DaveMunger, check the response's "Content-Type" header: `response.headers.get("content-type")`

Answer (score 7):

Try using text method of Body: `res.text()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `response.clone().json().catch(() => response.text())` as stated below

```
       fetch('/file')
         .then(response => 
             response.clone().json().catch(() => response.text())
         ).then(data => {
            // data is now parsed JSON or raw text
          });
```

By using **response.clone()** we can create a copy of the response to parse as JSON, and if that fails we parse the original response as text.

Thanks to *Steven Lambert* for his article [JSON with Text Fallback](https://stevenklambert.com/writing/fetch-json-text-fallback/) and *Jake Archibald* for his detailed article on [Reading responses](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/reading-responses/)